# Stored data is not same which I can access in file read loop

Tags: c

I have to read a txt with data in it. I can read it and store the data, but I don't know why, some stored data is not good after the read method.
Here is my output:

[image]

I write out these data with exactly the same code, except that the first is inside the loop and the second is outside of the loop.
I store these data in their own struct arrays. So as you can see, my problem is that I can't access my data outside that loop. What could be wrong?

Here is the full code: https://pastebin.com/wzEJqcZG
And the test data: https://pastebin.com/L7J133mz

This is inside the file read loop:

```
printf("%c %i - ", sorok[i].futarkod, sorok[i].datum);
for(j=0;j<sorok[i].rendelesCount;j++) {
    printf("%i%c", sorok[i].rendelesek[j].db, sorok[i].rendelesek[j].fajta);
}
printf("\n");
```

And this is outside of the file read loop:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
    printf("%c %i - ", sorok[i].futarkod, sorok[i].datum);
    for(j=0;j<sorok[i].rendelesCount;j++) {
        printf("%i%c ", sorok[i].rendelesek[j].db, sorok[i].rendelesek[j].fajta);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

In the output the first two columns are good, just the text after the dash is not.

Comment: I believe if you have a flexible array inside a struct like that, the struct cannot be used as an array member because its size can vary from instance to instance. Try using `rendeles **rendelesek;` instead (which must be allocated) or a fixed size array. `test.c:65:14: warning: 'sor' may not be used as an array element due to flexible array member [-Wflexible-array-extensions]  sor sorok[32];`.

Comment: Thank you, it's working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test.c:65:14: warning: 'sor' may not be used as an array element due to flexible array member
      [-Wflexible-array-extensions]
    sor sorok[32];
             ^
```

`rendeles rendelesek[];` is a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) meaning since it's at the end of the struct you can, in theory, allocate as much memory for the array as you like. However this means the size of any given `sor` will vary.

Each element of an array in C must be of a fixed size, going from one element to another is simply `start-of-array-memory + (i * sizeof(element))`. Since `sor` can be of different sizes it can't be put into an array.

You could use an array of pointers to `sor`, or you can change `sor` to contain a pointer to `rendeles **rendelesek;`. Or both, getting used to working with pointers is good.

---

The real problem is `sor.rendelesek` is never allocated. Whichever you choose, you still have to allocate memory to `sor.rendelesek` else you're writing into someone else's memory. As a flexible array member, you have to use a pointer array and allocate sufficient memory as part of `sor`.

```
typedef struct {
    char futarkod;
    int datum;
    int rendelesCount;
    rendeles rendelesek[];
} sor;

sor *sorok[32];
for( size_t i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    sorok[i] = malloc(sizeof(sor) + (sizeof(rendeles) * 32));
}
```

Or you can use a `rendelesek **` instead and allocate that directly. Combining both is probably the best option.

```
typedef struct {
    char futarkod;
    int datum;
    int rendelesCount;
    rendeles *rendelesek;
} sor;

sor *new_sor(const size_t num_rendeles) {
    sor *new = malloc(sizeof(sor));
    new->rendelesek = malloc(sizeof(rendeles) * num_rendeles);

    return new;
}

int main()
{
    sor *sorok[32];
    for( size_t i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        sorok[i] = new_sor(32);
    }
```

---

Reading inputs into statically allocated structures like this is risky and wasteful because you have to allocate what you *think* is the most possible elements. It's very easy to allocate way too much or not enough. Instead they should be dynamically allocated as needed, but that's another thing.